# Problem when trying to install Driconf

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, 20.04, gtk-2

I have a problem trying to install Driconf

```
*** Warning: importing GTK version 2 doesn't work.
*** Warning: DRIconf will probably not work for the above reason(s).
```

if anyone could help me I would be very grateful to use kubuntu 20.04
the version of Drifcon is driconf-0.9.1.tar.gz.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu 20.04 LTS does not have Python 2 GTK binding. So you have to get it first from the 19.10 repository by

```
sudo apt install python2
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
```

and then install the software

- from binary package

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/driconf/driconf_0.9.1-4_all.deb
  sudo apt-get install ./driconf_0.9.1-4_all.deb
  ```
- from source by

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget http://people.freedesktop.org/~fxkuehl/driconf/driconf-0.9.1.tar.gz
  tar -xf driconf-0.9.1.tar.gz
  sudo python2 setup.py install
  ```